# Set RTS settings inside program

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is it possible to set `RTS` options from within the program?

Specifically, I want to achieve the same as

`./my-prog +RTS -M4G`

I know that with haskell stack, you can decide some RTS options at compile time. But I don't want to fix these options at compile time, since I want my program to read these options from a configuration file and let it be aware of these options.

Is this possible with GHC?

Answer (score 3):

You could write some C code and override some GC hooks, but the easiest way might be to have a script set an environment variable.  The GHC Users Guide lists 4 ways RTS options can be set:
  https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#setting-rts-options

There are four ways to set RTS options:

- on the command line between +RTS ... -RTS, when running the program
  (Setting RTS options on the command line)
- at compile-time, using -with-rtsopts (Setting RTS options at compile
  time)
- with the environment variable GHCRTS (Setting RTS options with the
  GHCRTS environment variable)
- by overriding “hooks” in the runtime system (“Hooks” to change RTS
  behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe such options can be set from within the program itself, but can certainly be set at run-time the configuration parsing just has to be external to the program for which you want the RTS options set. You could write a program/script to read the configuration and run your target program passing the desired options.